# How to use different resources in android app based on user settings?

Tags: android, resources, settings

I am working on an application that asks the user for specific settings at the start. For example, my first activity asks the user:

Use option?

-option A

-option B

Now, after the user selects what option he/she will use I would like to be able to change the resources my app uses. I am specifically talking about the `values/strings.xml` where I have different strings for different options of the application.

For now, I am using option A as the default one and I put all the strings in the default strings.xml file and for now option B shares the same strings, however I am expecting option B to need a few specific strings that I will need to define in another file, but cannot figure out a way to decide what is the best approach to do this?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
To answer jkhouw1's question, option B will only change existing strings. If I was to use string arrays as resources, how would I be able to specify this in my layout.xml file and then be configured by what the user chose on the first activity? - to translate this in an example:

If I have a TextView I want to define its text in the layout.xml like `<TextView android:text="@string/(key)" />`

If I was to use string arrays for the not common strings, how could I define the `android:text` attribute for my View in the layout.xml file depending on what option the user selects?

Thanks

Comment: will option b need to simply change some of the existing strings?  or really use additional strings?  if the former, for those you want to toggle, you could put the strings in string arrays, and setting optiona=0 and optionb=1, you could get the position in the string array for the value you want- then you don't even need additional stringsb.xml.  if the latter, we would probably need more information as it seems rather application specific.

Comment: added more detail to the question, thanks for trying to help out

Comment: you can't specify the string in the xml - you would have to do it in code with yourTextView.setText(yourString[0]);  you can't specify the conditional in the xml as when it is being compiled, it doesn't yet know what option the user will select.

Comment: yep, that is the problem I am facing unfortunately. I don't want to have to write a bunch of code to customize my application to use raw string files, but I am guessing that is the only option. I thought maybe there's some way of doing this through using a Preference class or something of the sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to do what I am trying above currently.